# How do I save a CSV file on my computer which i have edited in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file-handling

I have used python to get rid of all the NaN values in a CSV file but I want to save the new file on my computer so I can open it through excel.

```
data = pd.read_csv('PAAD1.csv')
new_data = data.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')
print("Old data frame length:", len(data), "\nNew data frame length:",  
       len(new_data), "\nNumber of rows with at least 1 NA value: ", 
       (len(data)-len(new_data)))
```

Comment: `new_data.to_csv('filename.csv')`

Comment: where will this save the file?

Comment: in your working directory. you can set a full path aswell

Comment: Okay cool, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it to your current working directory using

`new_data.to_csv('PAAD1_noNA.csv')`

If you want it saved in another directory, then use

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'path/to/current/working/directory/'
new_data.to_csv(path + 'PAAD1_noNA.csv')
```